# initialize constructor with new inside class in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to C# programming. I want to know why this is not possible:

```
// In file1.cs
public class Test {

   public int Rt() {
      return 10;
   }
}
```

// In file2.cs

```
public class Test2 {
   // initialize constructor here, but return compile-error
   Test k = new Test();

   static void Main() {
    Console.Write(k.Rt());  // error here
   }
}
```

**Additional:** I am learning C# for unity, so I also want to know if above is not possible then why this is not an error in unity

```
public class PlayerScript: MonoBehaviour {
  public Vector2 speed = new Vector2(25, 25);   // Not an error

  void Update() {
    Debug.Log(speed);   // works
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting with `Console.Write(k.Rt());`?

Comment: What are these errors you're seeing?  Error messages have a tendency to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Error I'm getting: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Test2.k'`

Comment: `Test2.Main` is a static method, `PlayerScript.Update` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access an instance member inside a static method. That's not allowed. You can define `k` as static to make it work

```
static Test k = new Test();
```

I recommend you to take a look to [Static Classes and Static Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) to get more details

> The static member is callable on a class even when no instance of the class has been created. The static member is always accessed by the class name, not the instance name. Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are created. Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method parameter.

Comment: yes, I know this but can you tell me why it is possible in additional part (in unity) as `Vector2` is also a class

Comment: @ashish2expert: because on `PlayerScript` there is nothing `static`. The key here to undestand why your first example doesn't work is the static keyword. You cannot use instance members inside a static method because the static method doesn't belongs to any instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `Main` method is static but your `Test2` class is not static. The `k` variable lives in an instance of `Test2` but the `Main` method belongs to the type itself. If something is static, it means you can call it without instantiating a variable of that type:

```
Test2.Main();
```

If you attempted to instantiate a `Test2` and call `Main` you'd get an error because it's static.

```
var test2 = new Test2();
test2.Main(); //ERROR
```

You can make `k` static for this to compile:

```
public class Test2 {
   // initialize constructor here, but return compile-error
   static Test k = new Test();

   static void Main() {
       Console.Write(k.Rt());  // error here
   }
}
```

The second example you showed works fine because the `Update` method is *not* static, which means that the method lives with an instantiation of `PlayerScript`, unlike the `Main` method.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, another option is to make your `Test` class and `Rt` method static. Like so:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write(Test.Rt()); 
    }
}

public static class Test {

   public static int Rt() {
      return 10;
   }
}
```

You really don't have many cases to use a static class though they do exist. I would just move `Test t = new Test();` inside your `Main` method.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        Console.Write(t.Rt()); 
    }
}

public class Test {

   public int Rt() {
      return 10;
   }
}
```